# Where does Wordpress 4.x store custom css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm editing the custom CSS that my theme's author included via the built-in "Custom CSS" tab in the back end of Wordpress. I'd like to edit this info directly, though, with a proper text editor. Where is this info located? It's not in "style.css" in my child theme, and I can't figure out where else I should look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be happy about this: It's stored in the database (I just tried it), in the table named `wp_options`. Search the `option_value` field for something that's in your CSS (a class or id name, for example). But - at least in my case (when using the Divi theme) - it's saved together with tons of other settings in this one field...

Comment: Thanks.  I expected - but was hoping this wouldn't be - that this was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a child theme of your current theme, and place your styles in its style.css. Or copy and paste all of the custom css out of the theme's editor and work on it in a text editor, then copy back in and save.

Answer (score 1):

You can view wordpress Additional CSS in the wp_posts table with post type = custom_css

Answer (score 0):

[similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258226/where-are-additional-css-files-stored)

```
table: wp_posts 
post_type: custom_css
post_name: your theme slug
post_value: the css rules you want to change
```